# Thread Interruption Policy In Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

I am reading CIP by Goetz et. al. In the chapter on thread cancellation, the authors write:

> Just as task code should not make assumptions about what interruption
> means to its executing thread, cancellation code should not make
> assumptions about the interruption policy of arbitrary threads. A
> thread should be interrupted only by its owner; the owner can
> encapsulate knowledge of the thread’s interruption policy in an
> appropriate cancellation mechanism such as a shutdown method.

I understand that a task that is scheduled on some thread managed externally should either set the interrupted status back or throw the `InterruptedException` up the call stack to make sure that the owning thread is aware of the interruption and can execute whatever interruption policy it has (say, it might want to exit).

But for some reason, I am having trouble understanding this statement in the book. Why can't a task running on some thread request other threads to interrupt? How is it different from the task running on the same thread to interrupt its owning thread (by calling `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()`)?

Comment: Other authors have contributed to the book as well, for instance, Doug Lea and Joshua Blouch. I used CIP as the book is famous enough and the J is pretty much implied when your see the author's name.

Comment: A Thread should not be interrupted directly, but rather via something like a "shutdown"-method of its owner. This implies that you should not interact with an Thread object directly, but only via its owner. A good example is `ExecutorService`: It (most likely) manages (is the owner of) threads in its implementation. You should not interrupt the Threads of an `ExecutorService` by yourself (e.g. call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in a submitted Task). You should call `ExecutorService#shutdown()` instead, which internally should interrupt the Threads.